# Android Parse - localeIdentifier "en-IN" not getting notifications

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification

I am using Parse server in my android application. Everything is working fine in it except one issue. i.e. few devices not getting notifications. I noticed that in Installation table all devices which have localeIdentifier "en-IN" , not getting notifications.

Following is my Application class code -

```
 Parse.initialize(this, "myAppId","myAppClientId");
  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
   ParsePush.subscribeInBackground("mychannelname");
```

I am using latest Parse SDK 1.11.0.

What could be the issue?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you checking for locale in your Push code?

Comment: No. I am not checking for locale. Just passing the channel name in ParseQuery.